# weird screen tearing

Tags: monitor

I have an LG 43UD79-B monitor and it has this weird screen tearing on windows and in the corners. Please see the below screenshots. I'm running an Intel i7-4790K and an AMD 6970 GPU.  I also tried a second AMD GPU and had similar tearing issues.

[image]

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: ubuntu 18.04 KDE.  I also tried regular ubuntu 18.04 and same problem.  Both versions are 64 bit.